# Configuração do logo ao gerar apk na Unity 5

Tags: android, unity3d

Alguém sabe porque o logo da `Unity` no aparelho não fica na vertical 
segue a imagem para facilitar o entendimento

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu travei para ficar na posição vertical o resto da configuração não alterei nada

Comment: Hoje você tá afim de matar minhas respostas, de novo? :D Vou apagar aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não sei se entendi bem sua pergunta. Pelo que eu entendi o seu jogo é landscape mas a splash screen está em portrait?

Eu não saberia resolver sem olhar seu código ou configurações na unity, mas até aonde eu sei o logo da unity respeita a orientação sentada em Edit > Project Settings > Player > Resolution and Presentation. Se você tem mais de uma selecionada ele pode colocar como padrão o protrait, mas só para teste vá brincando com as configurações para entender melhor. Outra coisa que você pode fazer é colocar uma configuração como por exemplo "Apenas portrait" e girar o resto do seu jogo com o código:

```
Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
```

Basta colocá-lo em qualquer Start em seus scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu nao me engano o logo da unity com o celular em pe (portrait) é assim mesmo. Caso você esteja utilizando a unity pro você pode alterar a imagem.

Answer (score 0):

Na configuração do build (player settings), é possível escolher a orientação padrão do jogo (landscape, portrait, auto rotation, etc...).

**File -> Build Settings -> Player Settings -> Settings for iOS (ou) Settings for Android -> Resolution and Presentation -> Default Orientation**